# NoSuchMethodError for comparator?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I get the below exception on this line when I run my program in android.

```
private PriorityQueue<Creature> turnqueue = new PriorityQueue<Creature>(new TurnComparator());

FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 18092
Process: com.buckriderstudio.clonequest, PID: 10171
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V in class Ljava/util/PriorityQueue; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.PriorityQueue' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
```

This is how my comparator looks:

```
public class TurnComparator implements Comparator<Creature> {    
    @Override
    public int compare(Creature c1, Creature c2) {
        if (c1.getNextMove() < c2.getNextMove()) return -1;
        if (c1.getNextMove() > c2.getNextMove()) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }   
}
```

It seems it is some kind of compatibility issue but I'm not sure how to fix this. Does Android not support a `Comparator` at all or do I need to change it a bit to fix this? What would be a good compatible substitute for comparing a `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: What is the signature of `TurnComparator` ? Does it implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the java documentation, you will see that there is no such constructor for priority queue:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

You need to also specifify the initial capacity i.e.

```
private PriorityQueue<Creature> turnqueue = new PriorityQueue<Creature>(5, new TurnComparator());
```

Update: It's worth noting that this DOES work in Java 8 - they have added an extra constructor.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Comment: Yeah thanks. I'm using Java 8 that is why it runs on my Desktop. I better switch it to Java7 so everything I do is compatible with Android.

Comment: I've edited my answer to mention it does work in Java 8 as I hadn't realized that!

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList.sort() method was added later in API level 24 that's why its not working. There may be two solution either you can update java version or you can use below method.

```
 Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<Creature>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Creature c1, Creature c2) {
                if (c1.getNextMove() < c2.getNextMove()) return -1;
                if (c1.getNextMove() > c2.getNextMove()) return 1;
                else return 0;
            }
        });
```